# Kuberntes ingress and client auth application

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I have a springboot Application

I secured it by using spring security and X509 authentication as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.1/reference/html5/#servlet-x509)

So far, so good... all works as a charm.

Now I need to deploy it ad kubernetes app. Is it possible?

When I use K8S the K8S ingress controller "consumes" certificate and on my app it is missing.... Is it so? Can I configure it in order to leave the certificate so that I can find it in my `HttpServletRequest` attribute?

Thank you

Angelo

Comment: Hello, have you considered to use service of type `LoadBalancer` to send the traffic to your `Pods` without any facilities to "consume" your certificate? Also if you are using `nginx-ingress` you could look on `SSL passthrough`: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough

Comment: @DawidKruk I was just thinking about `SSL passthrough` but I didn't think about a service of type `LoadBalancer`; I'll give a look to both of them. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed in the comments:

> Hello, have you considered to use service of type LoadBalancer to send the traffic to your Pods without any facilities to "consume" your certificate? Also if you are using nginx-ingress you could look on SSL passthrough: [kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/…](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough)

Having a connection between a `Client` and a `Pod` in Kubernetes without "consuming" the certificate can be done by either:

- Service of type `LoadBalancer`
- `Ingress` controller with a `SSL` Passthrough

---

#### Service of type `Loadbalancer`

> LoadBalancer: Exposes the Service externally using a cloud provider's load balancer. NodePort and ClusterIP Services, to which the external load balancer routes, are automatically created.
>
> -- [Kubernetes.io: Service: LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)

You can configure a service that will expose your traffic externally on Layer4 (TCP/UDP). The traffic will be routed to your desired workload(Deployment/Statefulset).

Example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
  type: LoadBalancer
```

---

#### `Ingress controller` with a SSL Passthrough

You can also use `Ingress controller` capable of `SSL Passthrough`. One of the controllers with this feature is `ingress-nginx`:

> SSL Passthrough leverages [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and reads the virtual domain from the TLS negotiation, which requires compatible clients. After a connection has been accepted by the TLS listener, it is handled by the controller itself and piped back and forth between the backend and the client.
>
> This feature is implemented by intercepting all traffic on the configured HTTPS port (default: 443) and handing it over to a local TCP proxy. This bypasses NGINX completely and introduces a non-negligible performance penalty.
>
> -- [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: TLS: SSL passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough)

> Remember!
>
> The `--enable-ssl-passthrough` flag enables the SSL Passthrough feature, which is disabled by default.

---

As more of a workaround solution you can also look on the (there is an example in the link):

> #### Exposing TCP and UDP services
>
> Ingress does not support TCP or UDP services. For this reason this Ingress controller uses the flags `--tcp-services-configmap` and `--udp-services-configmap` to point to an existing config map where the key is the external port to use and the value indicates the service to expose using the format: `<namespace/service name>:<service port>:[PROXY]:[PROXY]`
>
> -- [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: Exposing tcp and udp services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/#exposing-tcp-and-udp-services)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I configured almost successfully the passthrough (i don't know why some resources loke css and js give me http status 502) but i'm wondering if this is the best approach because K8S documentation warns in performance issue. I'd like to use the LoadBalancer type solution but I don't understand how to expose my service. I see that the external IP is not assigned by K8S so.. what should I do to access to my application? I'm pretty newbie to K8S

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Using the service type of `LoadBalancer` depends on the solution you are using. `ExternalIP` assignment could be different for each of the solutions. Is the Kubernetes you are using a `minikube`,`kubeadm cluster`, managed solution like: `GKE`, `AKS`, `EKS`? It could come to the situation where you will need to use something like this : https://metallb.universe.tf/ .

Comment: Well the solution is private and installed inside my customer environment, no solution like  `GKE`, `AKS` or `EKS` is used. So, if I correctly understood, the `metallb` solution would be the correct way